# Can anyone offer advice on a S4 battery drain issue I"m having?

Tags: power-management, battery, hibernate

I'm having a problem with S4 hibernate on my Lenovo Thinkpad T440 on Ubuntu 20.04.01. I've been noticing that after leaving the machine in hibernate, there is significant battery drain happening. Example.... last night I had 56% on my "extra battery" (100% on the internal). Approximately 9-10 hours later - I'm down to 18% on the extra battery. With S4 there should be very little battery use as RAM is dumped to swap and all the internals should power down.

I've updated the BIOS to the latest. I cannot see any BIOS options related to sleep/hibernate.

Here are the kernel logs.... just don't know where to go from here.

```
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.420291] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.422887] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.476197] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.476198] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.769263] ACPI: EC: EC started
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.778163] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S4
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.784996] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [67999.930028] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.256367] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.256369] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.256371] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.256408] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.257449] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.257450] ata3.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.257452] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.257509] ata3.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:09:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.267670] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.267672] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.267673] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.287632] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/02:00:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.287634] ata1.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:a0 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
Dec 16 23:56:50 ThinkPad kernel: [68000.287635] ata1.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:03:00:00:00:a0 (SET FEATURES) filtered out
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.263743] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.266052] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S4
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.319058] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.319059] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.611285] ACPI: EC: EC started
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.622139] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S4
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.628760] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Dec 17 09:08:59 ThinkPad kernel: [68339.776254] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
```

Kernel bug perhaps???

Comment: Does this happen in other operating systems (Windows ?) or is it only specific to Ubuntu? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1300861/edit) your question to add this information.

Comment: I don't have Windows on this system.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like updating from Kernel 5.4 to 5.9 fixed the issue. In a 16 hour period in hibernation, the battery level dropped 1% vs the 20%+ on the previous kernel. The logs also show a specific ThinkPad ACPI module being loaded.

```
Dec 18 16:04:45 ThinkPad kernel: [   14.783480] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.26
Dec 18 16:04:45 ThinkPad kernel: [   14.787791] thinkpad_acpi: This ThinkPad has standard ACPI backlight brightness control, supported by the ACPI video driver
```

Comment: It may help future users if you write about how you updated the Kernel

Comment: Sure... good idea. I used the following resource: https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/. I used method #3, using the mainline application.